# I want to compile/install assimp with phtreads enabled over vcpkg on Windows. But i dont know how?

Tags: c++, pthreads, webassembly, vcpkg, assimp

So i am trying to write a simulation of clothing-behaviour in an web environment for my master-thesis with QtCreator.
Therefore i am developing a c++ cmake project and want to compile it with emscripten to WebAssembly which worked fine so far. Before knowing about using an external thread i used the WebAssembly Qt 6.6.2 (single-threaded) and now switched to the WebAssembly QT 6.6.2 (multi-threaded) Kit.

For the Simulation i want to use a Thread to calculate the physical behaviour indepented of my rendering context. I am on Windows and installed emscripten and vcpkg. With the emscripten cmd i installed assimp with the according triplet.

`SET VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET=wasm32-emscripten`

and then

`vcpkg install assimp`

Now in my code i import assets over assimp and that causes the following problem.

As soon as i use assimp     `Assimp::Importer m_importer;`
I get this ninja build error `:-1: Error: ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.`

And the compilation log states this:
`wasm-ld: error: --shared-memory is disallowed by 3DSLoader.cpp.o because it was not compiled with 'atomics' or 'bulk-memory' features.`

This brought me to the conclusion that i need to install assimp over vcpkg with pthreads enabled.
But i don't know how?

I already use these in my CMAkeLists.txt
`target_compile_options(Clothing-Simulator PRIVATE "-pthread")`
`target_link_options(Clothing-Simulator PRIVATE "-pthread")`

Can anyone provide some knowledge on this topic as i am unfamiliar with advanced CMake and vcpkg?
If i should provide any more ressources i will do.

I already know the option of Web-Workers/WASM-Workers but wanted to try pthreads first.

I already tried to compile it with pthreads on Flag, but i am using it wrong.

`vcpkg install assimp -DASSIMP_ENABLE_PTHREADS=ON`

gives  me

`<unknown>:1:9: error: invalid character in package name (must be lowercase, digits, '-') on expression: -dassimp_enable_pthreads=on`

`vcpkg install <port name> <port name>... vcpkg install zlib zlib:x64-windows curl boost`

so i guess i have to do otherwise. But as mentioned above i have little to zero expertise on this.

Thanks for any help